# Don't want IIS to autostart

Tags: windows-vista, boot, services, iis

I am using Windows Vista Ultimate, and in my current setup the IIS (webserver) starts up every time I start my computer.

How can I turn it off so IIS don't start on start up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply go to `Computer Management > Services and Applications > Services`

Then double click on `World Wide Publishing Service` and change it from `Automatic` to `Manual`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

bring up the services.msc then find the related tasks (I don't have an example currently) and set the service(s) to start manually.